# Comparing Next Item with Previous Item in a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, series

I would like to do a comparison among items in a pandas series. If the item is not equal to the next value, append to a list, else move on. I think my code is working, except it fails on the last occurrence because the index of items[k+1] is out of range. How do I get this to stop comparing on the last row?

I am doing this because I have a dataset supposedly ordered by date but I don't have a timestamp field. I only know starting month and year, and ending month and year.

However, one included field (the euribor3m field) is supposed to be a daily rate so I am hoping that I can separate out each day and then create a timestamp simply by comparing rows to the next row and noticing whether if the value for the field has changed. If it has, this would imply the new row maps to a new day, and since the rows are ordered by day I should hopefully get a total of x number of days matching the number of days between starting month-year and ending month-year

```
items = dict(enumerate(df['euribor3m']))
unique = []

for k,i in items.items():
    if items[k+1] != items[k]:
        unique.append(items[k+1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to catch `KeyError`:

```
for k, i in items.items():
    try:
        if items[k+1] != items[k]:
            unique.append(items[k+1])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

But you shouldn't be iterating this way in the first place, as Pandas specialises in vectorised operations. You can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'euribor3m': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]})

res = df.loc[df['euribor3m'].shift(-1) != df['euribor3m']]

print(res)

#    euribor3m
# 1          1
# 2          2
# 3          3
# 4          4
# 6          5
# 7          6
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer as it’s not only the most elegant but also explains the problem in detail

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shift()` for this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'euribor3m':[5,5,7,7,8,9,11,11,34,45,45]})

df0 = df.shift()

mask = df['euribor3m']==df0['euribor3m']
df_new = df[mask]
print(list(df_new['euribor3m']))
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 11, 45]
```